# Making form elements on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, cordova

I am currently make an app and I am trying to make 3 form element align (25/25/50) whoever, it seems like it has not been going smoothly. I will attach a picture at the end to show how it is looking right now. Also, if possible, is there anyway I can make the 3 form element have a space between them so that it is easier to be read and interpreted?

```
Between
<div class="ui-grid-e">
  <div class=ui-block-a><input type="text" name="between1" id="between1" required /></div>
  <div class=ui-block-b><input type="text" name="between2" id="between2" required /></div>
  Comment
  <div class=ui-block-c><input type="text" name="betweencomment" id="betweencomment" required /></div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfA3Q.jpg

Comment: Try using box-sizing: border-box property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update your markup

```css
.ui-grid-e {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}

.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b,
.ui-block-c {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 5px;
}

.ui-block-a{
padding-left: 0;
}

.title-c {
padding-left: 5px;
}

.ui-block-title{
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

.ui-block-c{
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

input {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-grid-e">
                     <div class="ui-block-title title-a-b">Between</div>
                     <div class="ui-block-title title-c">Comment</div>
                        <div class=ui-block-a><input type="text" name="between1" id="between1" required /></div>
                        <div class=ui-block-b><input type="text" name="between2" id="between2" required /></div>
                        
                        <div class=ui-block-c><input type="text" name="betweencomment" id="betweencomment" required /></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: +1 It has turned out how I would like it to be. Thank you so much for helping me! Have a wonderful day! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use for html as followed:

```
<form class="ui-grid-e">
       <input type="text" name="between1" id="between1"  />
       <input type="text" name="between2" id="between2"  />
       <input type="text" name="betweencomment" id="betweencomment"/>
</form>
```

and in your css :

```
.ui-grid-e{ 

display: inline;

float: left;


}
```